# >=Rails 3.1 how to include IE specific YAML-CSS file in asset pipeline

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, conditional-statements, yaml-css

How to include the Yaml-CSS suit's iehacks.css?
The yaml documentation points to something like this conditional statement.

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>         
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/yaml/core/iehacks.css" type="text/css"/>
<![endif]-->
```

How do I include that css file in my Rails 3.1++ app (dependent on IE or not IE ;) with the new rails pipelining features in mind?

Comment: You can't really package this with the rest of the files you'd combine into `application.css` because you want the conditional wrapping the `<link>` tag for these ie-only styles. There's an already-minified version of the file available at `stylesheets/yaml/core/iehacks.min.css`. Why not just point to that? Do you have many other `lte IE 7` stylesheets you want to pack together?

Answer (score 0):

In your **config/application.rb**, add a line like that:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w(iehacks.css)
```

Only files inside the "application" manifest are automatically used for precompilation.

Extra files must be declared manually.

I hope this helps and sorry about my english.